# Determining a action source in a custom validator

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

There's a form with a `selectOneMenu` which could be submitted both by AJAX and a `commandButton`:

```
<h:form>
  ...
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBackingBean.officeId}" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="[not selected]"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBackingBean.officeSelectItems}"/>
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="officeSelect"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  ...
  <h:commandButton
    id="okButton"
    value="ОК"
    action="#{myBackingBean.login}"
  />
</h:form>
```

I'm looking for a way to develope a custom validator for the `selectOneMenu` that should validate a value only if it's submitted by the `commandButton`. Is it possible to recognize a way the value is submitted with in a custom validator class?

Comment: Why you need custom validator for that? Do it in action of `commandButton` (login method in your case).

Comment: Using a validator I'll have a message on a validation fail.

Comment: The same message you can add in action method for fail case.

Comment: `login` is invoked not only in a JSF context. Therefore I think it would be a bad solution to put JSF-specific code into the method.

Comment: You can wrap it in another method then, one that will produce a message if needed. It's possible to determine the source in JSF 2, I'm not sure if and how it's done in JSF 1.2